# run a ruby program on startup

Tags: server, bash, ruby

I have written a small webSocket server using ruby. I run it from the command line using the command:

```
ruby websocket_server.rb
```

This will bring the server up and will work till I keep my ssh connection open and running (I'm doing this on a server that is in a remote server farm so no direct access). 
I'd like to understand how to write two scripts: one that will start the ruby program on startup and the other that will check (say every 30 minutes) if the program is up and running. 
As a sidenote my final goal is to have a "button" on a  php dashboard to start the process again if it hangs without having to wait for the check&restart process (I'm already able to check the process status).

Comment: I think this is a cross-site duplicate. You should check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/696839/how-do-i-write-a-bash-script-to-restart-a-process-if-it-dies), on StackOverflow

Comment: traditionally this is done with init, upstart, or systemd, depending on which release of ubuntu you have. What is your release? Also, if 15 have you chosen upstart or systemd?

Comment: @Ploutox thanks for the hint. Maybe I' wrong but isn't this better to post this kind of questions on this site than on SO?

Comment: @meuh I am working with Ubuntu server 14.04.2 LTS (trusty).

Comment: Technically, the question would be valid on SO as there is a part of it that is solved through the use of bash programming. But it is perfectly valid here, and would be on topic on Unix/Linux SE as well as your problem is not specific to Ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 14.04 uses **upstart**, so you can write a small config file saying
how you want upstart to manage your service, which, for example, you
name "myweb".  Using sudo create a file called `/etc/init/myweb.conf` (a
symbolic link from there to a real file will not work) with contents
something like:

```
description "run webSocket server when network ready"
start on static-network-up
respawn
exec ruby websocket_server.rb
```

You can test this out with

```
sudo start myweb
status myweb
sudo stop myweb
```

The `status` command will show if the process is still running. `respawn` says  you
would like it automatically restarted if it dies. The start, stop, and status commands are all just links to initctl.
See `man initctl`, `man 5 init` for the conf file format, and the [upstart cookbook](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/).

Comment: so I can use the answer posted on SO and referred to by @ploutox to keep the service named myweb up and running! Thanks for the good hint!

Comment: @LelioFaieta No, with this single conf file everything is already handled for you. Your service program is started at boot, and if the program stops it will be restarted, provided you add the `respawn` line in the .conf file.

Comment: so after `exec ruby websocket_server.rb` i should just add a line with `respawn`? Am I right here?

Comment: @LelioFaieta Yes. Typically `exec` is the last line, but you can use any order. I've edited my answer to use `respawn` in the file. Obviously, you'll need to replace `websocket_server.rb` by the full name to the ruby file.